# jQuery Performance: Multiple Selectors vs. Selector with Context

Tags: jquery, performance, selector

Wondering which of the following is considered the *right* way of doing things. If I have the following html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="form">
        <div class="field">TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to retrieve the text in **field** using jQuery, which is better (and why). Multiple selectors:

```
$("#container #form .field").text();
```

Or using context:

```
$((".field", $("#form")), $("#container")).text();
```

Here is a fiddle containing both: http://jsfiddle.net/f8LKc/

Comment: Is there any reason why you would need all three identities? An identity should be unique in the page, so normally you should only need to use one.

Comment: If you're using `id`s the fastest should just be `$('#field')`.

Comment: sorry, say that `field` is the class of the inner div (see adjusted question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like running a benchmark to test the performance of both approaches. I've created a test case at jsperf.com, testing your two approaches, as well as a select by class `$(".field")`:

```
Testing in Chrome 21.0.1180.89 32-bit on Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 64-bit Test 

+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| Test                  | Ops/sec                   |
+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| Multiple Selector     |  43,265  67% slower       |
+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| Selector w/ Context   | 130,051  fastest          |
+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| Selector w/ Class     | 126,064  2% slower        |
+-----------------------+---------------------------+
```

**[TEST CASE](http://jsperf.com/multiplevscontextselector/4)**.

Comment: cool thanks for this. i modified the test case to have field be a class instead of an id to match the revised question: http://jsperf.com/multiplevscontextselector/4

Comment: @DougieBear: Oh, ok, didn't see that. I've edited my answer to reflect your modification's result for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

You should just use `$('#field')` since it is an ID selector there will be only one instance of `<div id="field">`.

Comment: I would give that answer, if you would not give it earlier.

Comment: sorry, say that field is the class of the inner div (see adjusted question)